# Derivative of $v^T A(x) w$ with respect to $x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $x \mapsto A(x)$ be a matrix-valued function and let $v, w$ be fixed vectors of compatible dimension such that the map $$v^T A(x) w$$ is well-defined and takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. What is the following derivative?

$$\frac{\partial v^TA(x)w}{\partial x}$$

I feel like it should be matrix-valued but I'm having trouble showing it. I've taken a look at the matrix-calculus cookbook and still no luck.

Comment: What is $x$? Scalar? Vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, your "matrix function" takes a real argument $x$ and gives a complex-valued matrix $A(x)$. Let $v, w$ be vectors such as you defined, and

$$f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \\
x \mapsto v^TA(x)w$$

Your question simply pertains to derivating $f$, so as you can see the result is simply a complex-valued function of a real argument.

Now, as to computing said derivative, writing $x \mapsto A(x)$ is actually hiding the fact that every cell of $A$ is expressed in terms of $x$, so derivating the above function in regards to $x$ (which by the way is a normal derivative and not a partial one) gives a matrix whose cells are the derivatives of the cells in regards to $x$, and :

$$f'(x) = v^TA'(x)w$$

which is still a complex-valued function of a real argument.

Comment: Oh well that was quite simple actually... thanks! :)